# Is there a better way to mark all buttons isClickable property to false?

Tags: android, kotlin, button

Need help to get a better way for changing all the buttons isClickable property at once

```
    private fun enableOrDisable(trueOrfalse: Boolean){
    for(i in 1..9){
        when(i){
            1 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1).isClickable = trueOrfalse
            2 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2).isClickable = trueOrfalse
            3 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3).isClickable = trueOrfalse
            4 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button4).isClickable = trueOrfalse
            5 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button5).isClickable = trueOrfalse
            6 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button6).isClickable = trueOrfalse
            7 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button7).isClickable = trueOrfalse
            8 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button8).isClickable = trueOrfalse
            9 -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.button9).isClickable = trueOrfalse
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not you use recylerView , or you can use data binding as well

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would be to create a list of all `ids` and iterating over each of them

```
private fun enableOrDisable(trueOrfalse: Boolean){
    listOf<Int>(
                R.id.button1,
                R.id.button2,
                R.id.button3,
                R.id.button4,
                R.id.button5,
                R.id.button6,
                R.id.button7,
                R.id.button8,
                R.id.button9
            ).forEach {
                findViewById<Button>(it).isClickable = trueOrfalse
            }
    }
```